# How to add overlaying view like silhouette on default camera application

Tags: android, kotlin

So I am currently developing an app with function for overlaying Views or Images in Camera Preview. I have tried this code:

```
btn_Capture.setOnClickListener {
        //if system os is Marshmallow or Above, we need to request runtime permission
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED ||
                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
                //permission was not enabled
                val permission = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                //show popup to request permission
                requestPermissions(permission, PERMISSION_CODE)
            }
            else{
                //permission already granted
                showDialog()
                //openCamera()
            }
        }
        else{
            //system os is < marshmallow
            showDialog()
            //openCamera()
        }
    }
```

And here's my showDialog function:

```
private fun showDialog(){
    val listItems = arrayOf("3 meters", "4 meters", "5 meters", "6 meters", "7 meters", "8 meters", "9 meters", "10 meters", "11 meters")

    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity)
    builder.setTitle("Choose distance of viewport")

    val checkedItem = 0 //this will checked the item when user open the dialog
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(
        listItems, checkedItem
    ) { dialog, which ->
        SelectedRadio = listItems[which]
    }

    builder.setPositiveButton(
        "Go"
    ) { dialog, which -> dialog.dismiss()
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,SelectedRadio,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        openCamera()
    }

    val dialog = builder.create()
    dialog.show()
}
```

So i want to overlay an image every time I open the camera app. I also tried creating custom layout and attaching it to the parent of the camera but it doesn't work the way I want to.

Comment: I have fixed it myself. I used Fotoapparat Library then  enabled the Hardware acceleration in the Manifest File then disabled the hardware acceleration for the image that is going to overlay on top of the camera preview

Answer (score 1):

So I have done it this way

Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/temaiconfinalllll"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/temaiconfinalllll"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".CustomCamera2"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:label="CustomCamera2"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

This is my Custom Camera Activity

```
class CustomCamera2 : AppCompatActivity() {

   lateinit var newView: ImageView
   var pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
   var simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(pattern)
   var date = simpleDateFormat.format(Date())
   var fotoapparat: Fotoapparat? = null
   var filename = date + "Tema.png"
   val sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
   val finalsd = sd.toString() + "/Pictures"
   var dest = File(finalsd, filename)
   var fotoapparatState : FotoapparatState? = null
   var cameraStatus : CameraState? = null
   var flashState: FlashState? = null
   val permissions = arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.content_custom_camera2)
       createFotoapparat()
       cameraStatus = CameraState.BACK
       flashState = FlashState.OFF
       fotoapparatState = FotoapparatState.OFF

       myview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE,null)

       fab_camera.setOnClickListener {
           takePhoto()
       }

       fab_switch_camera.setOnClickListener {
           switchCamera()
       }

       fab_flash.setOnClickListener {
           changeFlashState()
       }

   }

   private fun createFotoapparat(){
       val cameraView = findViewById<CameraView>(R.id.camera_view)

       fotoapparat = Fotoapparat(
           context = this,
           view = cameraView,
           scaleType = ScaleType.CenterCrop,
           lensPosition = back(),
           logger = loggers(
               logcat()
           ),
           cameraErrorCallback = { error ->
               println("Recorder errors: $error")
           }
       )
   }

   private fun changeFlashState() {
       fotoapparat?.updateConfiguration(
           CameraConfiguration(
              flashMode = if(flashState == FlashState.TORCH) off() else torch()
           )
       )

       if(flashState == FlashState.TORCH) flashState = FlashState.OFF
       else flashState = FlashState.TORCH
   }

   private fun switchCamera() {
       fotoapparat?.switchTo(
           lensPosition =  if (cameraStatus == CameraState.BACK) front() else back(),
           cameraConfiguration = CameraConfiguration()
       )

       if(cameraStatus == CameraState.BACK) cameraStatus = CameraState.FRONT
       else cameraStatus = CameraState.BACK
   }

   private fun takePhoto() {
       if (hasNoPermissions()) {
        requestPermission()
       }else{
           fotoapparat
               ?.takePicture()
               ?.saveToFile(dest)

           Handler().postDelayed(
               {
                   StartEdit()
               },
               1300 // value in milliseconds
           )

       }
   }

   fun StartEdit(){
       val dest2:String = dest.absolutePath.toString()
       val intent = Intent(this,EditActivity2::class.java)
       intent.putExtra("ImagePath", dest2)
       startActivity(intent)

       Toast.makeText(this,dest.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
       pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
       simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(pattern)
       date = simpleDateFormat.format(Date())
       filename = date + "Tema.png"
       dest = File(finalsd, filename)
   }

   override fun onStart() {
       super.onStart()
       if (hasNoPermissions()) {
           requestPermission()
       }else{
           fotoapparat?.start()
           fotoapparatState = FotoapparatState.ON
       }
   }

   private fun hasNoPermissions(): Boolean{
       return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
           Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
           Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
           Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
   }

   fun requestPermission(){
       ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions,0)
   }

   override fun onStop() {
       super.onStop()
       fotoapparat?.stop()
       FotoapparatState.OFF
   }

   override fun onResume() {
       super.onResume()
       if(!hasNoPermissions() && fotoapparatState == FotoapparatState.OFF){
           val intent = Intent(baseContext, MainActivity::class.java)
           startActivity(intent)
           finish()
       }
   }

   enum class CameraState{
       FRONT, BACK
   }

   enum class FlashState{
       TORCH, OFF
   }

   enum class FotoapparatState{
       ON, OFF
   }
}
```

Then this is my Xml File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@id/relativelayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@android:color/black">


    <io.fotoapparat.view.CameraView
        android:id="@+id/camera_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>



    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_camera"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        android:src="@drawable/camera"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="32dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_flash"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        android:src="@drawable/torch"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="32dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_switch_camera"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        android:src="@drawable/palit"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"/>

    <!--<com.google.android.material.transformation.TransformationChildLayout
        android:id="@+id/Hello"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/guidethree"/>-->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/guidethree"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
```